# Change the color of listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created 2 columns. Name of the student and score.
I want to change the colour to red of column 2 which is the "Score" that have below 89% scores. below is my code: however every time a get a value of 100% the color still change to red. please help me guys.

```
  For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.Items
        Dim va As String = 89%

        If lvi.SubItems(2).Text < va Then

            lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
            lvi.SubItems(2).ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: The string `"100"` **is** 'less' than `"89%"` - change your comparisons to work with a numeric type.

Comment: And turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: Ouch, 89% doesn't do what he thinks either.  It doesn't mean "percentage" and that string doesn't actually have "%" at all.  Lovely how newbie VB programmers can shoot their foot :)

Comment: Ouch :( haha anyway i'll do your advise. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Use integer comparison and make sure that the column content is not an empty string
Try this:

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.Items

    Dim va As integer= 89
    Dim tmpColumnValue as string

 If (not string.isNullorEmpty(lvi.SubItems(2).Text)) then
    tmpColumnValue =lvi.SubItems(2).Text.TrimEnd('%')

    If (not string.isNullorEmpty(tmpColumnValue)) and (cInt(tmpColumnValue )) < va Then
        lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
        lvi.SubItems(2).ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
 end if
```

Next

Comment: MSG ERROR" Conversion from string "85.79%" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
85.79% is the value of column score :(